# SQL View only returns one row

Tags: sql, view, count, sequelpro

I'm trying to create a view that returns the amount of courses each Californian student is enrolled in. There are 4 CA students listed in my 'Students' table, so it should return that many rows.

```
create or replace view s2018_courses as 
select Students.*, COUNT(Current_Schedule.ID) EnrolledCourses
from Students, Current_Schedule
where Students.ID = Current_Schedule.ID AND state='CA';
```

This query, however, only returns a single row with one student's information, and the total number of courses all CA students are in (in this case 14, since each student is enrolled in 3-5 classes).

I created a view similar to this recently (in a different DB) and it worked well and executed multiple rows, so I'm not sure what is going wrong? Sorry if this is a confusing question, I'm new to SQL and StackOverflow!! Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an aggregation step in your query/view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW s2018_courses AS 
SELECT
    s.ID, COUNT(cs.ID) EnrolledCourses
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN Current_Schedule cs
    ON s.ID = cs.ID
WHERE
    state = 'CA'
GROUP BY
    s.ID;
```

The logical problem with your current query is that you are using `COUNT(*)` without `GROUP BY`, and MySQL is interpreting this to mean that you want to take the count of the entire table.  Note also that I only select `ID` in my query above, because this is what is being used to aggregate.